# bash - IFS changes behavior of echo -n in for loop

Tags: bash

I have code that requires a response within a for loop.

Prior to the loop I set `IFS="\n"`

Within the loop `echo -n` is ignored (except for the last line).

Note: this is just an example of the behavior of `echo -n`

Example:

> ```
>    IFS='\n'
>     for line in `cat file`
>     do
>     echo -n $line
>     done
> ```

This outputs:

> 1. this is a test
> 2. this is a test
> 3. this is a test$

with the user prompt occuring only at the end of the last line.

Why is this occuring and is there a fix?

Comment: Try `for line in $(IFS='\n' cat file); do ...`

Comment: There is no need to use `cat` and `IFS`

Answer (score 6):

Neither `IFS="\n"` nor `IFS='\n'` set `$IFS` to a *newline*; instead they set it to *literal* `\` followed by *literal* `n`.

You'd have to use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in order to assign an actual newline: `IFS=$'\n'`; alternatively, you could use a normal string literal that contains an *actual* newline (spans 2 lines).

Assigning *literal* `\n` had the effect that the output from `cat file` was *not* split into lines, because an actual newline was not present in `$IFS`; potentially - though not with your sample file content - the output could have been split into fields by embedded `\` and `n` characters.
Without either, the *entire* file contents were passed *at once*, resulting in  a *single* iteration of your `for` loop.

---

That said, your approach to looping over lines from a file is [ill-advised](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); try something like the following instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo -n "$line"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use for loops when parsing files in bash. Use while loops instead. Here is a really good tutorial on that.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001